# Empty World in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that you can create an empty world in Minecraft Java Edition, but is there a way to do it in Minecraft Bedrock?
I have looked in many places, and not found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a superflat then just put something like:

```
/fill ~-50 0 ~-50 ~50 3 ~50 air
```

to clear the area around you. Just run around and run that command wherever you need an empty spot.

**Custom superflats are not available in Bedrock Edition, only legacy console (general & PS4) & Java.**

Comment: Is it possible to have the *whole* world empty?

Comment: @EmojiMaker sadly not. What you are asking for is custom superflats and unfortunately even though so many people want them they haven't been added to Bedrock. I can't see them coming in the too near future, but maybe somtime?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_imjIrt_UI4), it says that if you create a flat world with the seed `-94187608`, it will be a complete void.

Comment: @EmojiMaker that's not what that video is saying; it is distributing a world download, that seed was just the random seed he used for the world. You can definitely download that map though, but it's not built into the game

Comment: I'll try that world.